# Can I use a List<string> as Choice Parameters for a Slash Command?

Tags: c#, discord.net

Reading the documentation of Discord.Net, I found that I can use an Enum as parameter of my module to allow my users to pick a value from the enum when they type a slash command :

```
public class CharacterChoiceModule : InteractionModuleBase<SocketInteractionContext>
{
    [SlashCommand("personnage", "test")]
    public async Task Choice(PersonnageName personnage)
    {
        ...
    }
}

public enum PersonnageName
{
    Gérard,
    Daniel
}
```

It results as a pickable PersonnageName that I can use in my code with the variable `personnage` passed as parameter. The Ui of the choice is the following :
[image]

But now I want to pass a dynamic list of choices, for example a `List<string>` that I could populate through a database.

Is it possible to use a dynamic List as Choice Parameters for a Slash Command ?

Comment: Does a `List<ApplicationCommandOptionChoiceProperties>` work? I ask because of [this code](https://github.com/discord-net/Discord.Net/blob/fb4250b88c14ad802079f25931739df170c1dc35/src/Discord.Net.Interactions/TypeConverters/SlashCommands/EnumConverter.cs#L21-L42).

Comment: Unfortunately I can't populate it before calling the command. I can inject it through the DI in the constructor, but I don't have any possibilities to pass it to the method

Comment: The answer provided by **gunr2171** is correct. Choices have to be registered with the command (that's required by Discord). What you can possibly use would be the auto-complete option, as that can be generated dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. All choices must be declared when you register the slash command. This is a limitation of the Discord API, not the C# library.